# Testing multiple JavaFX components using JemmyFX

Tags: java, junit, javafx-2, jemmy, jemmyfx

I am working on a fairly large project which includes a set of custom JavaFX components. For each custom component which is meant to be reused, I have started to write a set of automated tests using JemmyFX and JUnit. During development, I run these from inside Eclipse Juno.

Running the entire suite of tests at once has proven difficult. The problem seems to stem from the fact since I want to test multiple components, I would ideally run a different application for each (so that tests performed on one component do not affect other tests).

I created a base class which does the following:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {

    Thread t = new Thread("JavaFX Init Thread") {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Application.launch(UITester.class, new String[0]);
        }
    };

    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

Using this base class, I created a separate class with `@Test` tests for each custom control. When I run this test suite, the first test case runs fine, but the rest fail:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Init Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
```

I have tried the following ways to address this problem:

#### Shut down the application

I  added the following to the base class:

```
@AfterClass
public static void afterClass() {
    Platform.exit();
}
```

Same problem persists. Perhaps because the VM is not restarted between tests?

#### Put in a guard against restarting the application

I put in a static variable to check and see if perhaps the application is already running. This makes the problem go away when I run the tests from Eclipse. When I run them from the command line, the problem is still there. Not good for when we try to run these tests on the integration server.

#### Catch the IllegalStateException

This is an odd one. I can catch the exception, and most of my problems go away, except for the fact that every 4 or 5 runs of the entire test suite Ubuntu crashes to the shell and I have to log back in.

So, how do I best write tests for a large suite of custom controls? Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: Not on my PC now but I think JemmyFx has a special class (AppExecutor?) to run the Application - that might solve your issue. Alternatively you could run each test class in a new VM (junit probably has a parameter to do that) but that will be show.

Comment: @assylias Yeah, `AppExecutor.executeNoBlock(UITester.class);` As far as I understand it, it does the same thing as my original sample (and was the call I originally made to start the tests, with the same effect).

Comment: I just stumbled across [MarvinFX](https://github.com/guigarage/MarvinFX) which has a promising way of doing what I am trying to do.

Comment: I have the same problem. Awaiting for a better solution, i put only one test method per test class. On the CI, each test is run in a separate jvm. For eclipse, i use the same solution (static flag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the source of [MarvinFX](https://github.com/guigarage/MarvinFX) I was able to  implement our test framework in a fashion that addresses my problems. What appears to have contributed most to fix this problem was rebuilding the stage and scene for every test, as demonstrated in this (pseudo) code:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    Node node = generateComponentToTest();
    Parent parent = StackPaneBuilder.create().children(node).build();
    Scene scene = SceneBuilder.create().root(parent).build();

    if (this.currentStage != null) {
        this.currentStage.close();
    }

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();

    this.currentStage = stage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by checking the current threads - if "JavaFX Init Thread" is one of them, just return from the `initJavaFX()`.

```html
    public synchronized void initJavaFX() throws InterruptedException {
        if (isThreadAlreadyRunning()) {
            return;
        }

        Thread t = new Thread(JAVA_FX_INIT_THREAD_NAME) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Application.launch(DummyFXApp.class);
            }
        };
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

    }

    private static boolean isThreadAlreadyRunning() {
        return Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().stream()
            .map(Thread::getName)
            .anyMatch(it -> it.equals(JAVA_FX_INIT_THREAD_NAME));
    }
```

Comment: what is the first line of the code? `public synchronized void initJavaFX() throws InterruptedException {` i do not think it will work.